# Python request session ignore verify settings

Tags: python, ssl, python-requests

I am using latest request version `2.25.1`, and when I set `session.verify = False` it still try to validate SSL certs.

Here is my code sample.

```
import requests
session = requests.session()

headers = {'content-type': 'application/json',
 'accept': 'application/json',
 'user-agent': 'PyU4V/9.2.1.3 (Linux; version 3.10.0-957.27.2.el7.x86_64) Python 3.7.3',
 'application-type': 'PyU4V-9.2.1.3'}
session.headers = headers

username = "username"
password = "password"
session.auth = HTTPBasicAuth(username, password)

session.verify = False
url = 'https://X.X.X.X:8443/univmax/restapi/version'

session.request(method='GET', url=url)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
SSLCertVerificationError                  Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py in urlopen(self, method, url, body, headers, retries, redirect, assert_same_host, timeout, pool_timeout, release_conn, chunked, body_pos, **response_kw)
    705                 headers=headers,
--> 706                 chunked=chunked,
    707             )

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py in _make_request(self, conn, method, url, timeout, chunked, **httplib_request_kw)
    381         try:
--> 382             self._validate_conn(conn)
    383         except (SocketTimeout, BaseSSLError) as e:

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py in _validate_conn(self, conn)
   1009         if not getattr(conn, "sock", None):  # AppEngine might not have  `.sock`
-> 1010             conn.connect()
   1011

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/urllib3/connection.py in connect(self)
    420             ssl_context=context,
--> 421             tls_in_tls=tls_in_tls,
    422         )

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py in ssl_wrap_socket(sock, keyfile, certfile, cert_reqs, ca_certs, server_hostname, ssl_version, ciphers, ssl_context, ca_cert_dir, key_password, ca_cert_data, tls_in_tls)
    431     else:
--> 432         ssl_sock = _ssl_wrap_socket_impl(sock, context, tls_in_tls)
    433     return ssl_sock

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py in _ssl_wrap_socket_impl(sock, ssl_context, tls_in_tls, server_hostname)
    473     else:
--> 474         return ssl_context.wrap_socket(sock)

/usr/lib/python3.7/ssl.py in wrap_socket(self, sock, server_side, do_handshake_on_connect, suppress_ragged_eofs, server_hostname, session)
    411             context=self,
--> 412             session=session
    413         )

/usr/lib/python3.7/ssl.py in _create(cls, sock, server_side, do_handshake_on_connect, suppress_ragged_eofs, server_hostname, context, session)
    852                         raise ValueError("do_handshake_on_connect should not be specified for non-blocking sockets")
--> 853                     self.do_handshake()
    854             except (OSError, ValueError):

/usr/lib/python3.7/ssl.py in do_handshake(self, block)
   1116                 self.settimeout(None)
-> 1117             self._sslobj.do_handshake()
   1118         finally:

SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate (_ssl.c:1056)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

MaxRetryError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/requests/adapters.py in send(self, request, stream, timeout, verify, cert, proxies)
    448                     retries=self.max_retries,
--> 449                     timeout=timeout
    450                 )

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py in urlopen(self, method, url, body, headers, retries, redirect, assert_same_host, timeout, pool_timeout, release_conn, chunked, body_pos, **response_kw)
    755             retries = retries.increment(
--> 756                 method, url, error=e, _pool=self, _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2]
    757             )

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py in increment(self, method, url, response, error, _pool, _stacktrace)
    573         if new_retry.is_exhausted():
--> 574             raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
    575

MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='X.X.X.X', port=8443): Max retries exceeded with url: /univmax/restapi/version (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate (_ssl.c:1056)')))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

SSLError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-61-d1c0089b962c> in <module>
----> 1 session.request(method='GET', url=url)

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py in request(self, method, url, params, data, headers, cookies, files, auth, timeout, allow_redirects, proxies, hooks, stream, verify, cert, json)
    540         }
    541         send_kwargs.update(settings)
--> 542         resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
    543
    544         return resp

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py in send(self, request, **kwargs)
    653
    654         # Send the request
--> 655         r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
    656
    657         # Total elapsed time of the request (approximately)

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/requests/adapters.py in send(self, request, stream, timeout, verify, cert, proxies)
    512             if isinstance(e.reason, _SSLError):
    513                 # This branch is for urllib3 v1.22 and later.
--> 514                 raise SSLError(e, request=request)
    515
    516             raise ConnectionError(e, request=request)

SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='X.X.X.X', port=8443): Max retries exceeded with url: /univmax/restapi/version (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate (_ssl.c:1056)')))
```

When I pass `verify=False` in request, it return me proper response.

```
session.request(method='GET', url=url, verify=False)
<Response [200]>
```

I check the `session` Code, where `verify` set to [`True`](https://github.com/psf/requests/blob/v2.25.1/requests/sessions.py#L397) by default.

But when we set explicitly `session.verify = False` it should ignore the SSL.

Comment: Your code is pretty straight forward and as you said passing parameter directly gave proper response, then it might be a bug. There is also a similar issue like yours, check this out(https://github.com/psf/requests/issues/3829). If it isn't same, you can create a new issue.

Comment: Yes its same issue, but I am using another library, which has code as [`session.verify = False`](https://github.com/dell/PyU4V/blob/master/PyU4V/rest_requests.py#L69-L78). I don't have control over that library, need to fix on request side. Do you have any suggestion to bypass this ?